# Bingbot ignoring robots.txt and attempting to retrieve a trafficbasedsspsitemap.xml

Tags: bing, robots.txt, bingbot

I have an app whose content should not be publicly indexed.  I've therefore disallowed access to all crawlers.

robots.txt:

```
# Robots shouldn't index a private app.
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

However, Bing has been ignoring this and daily requests a `/trafficbasedsspsitemap.xml` file, which I have no need to create.

I also have no need to receive daily 404 error notifications for this file.  I'd like to just make the bingbot go away, so what do I need to do to forbid it from making requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44257/bingbot-request-for-trafficbasedsspsitemap-xml-which-does-not-exist#answer-44339), this is Bingbot checking for an XML sitemap generated by the Bing Sitemap Plugin for IIS and Apache. It apparently cannot be blocked by robots.txt.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming from google-

You could block bots via apache user agent detection/ rewrite directives, that would allow you to keep bingbot out entirely.
https://superuser.com/questions/330671/wildcard-blocking-of-bots-in-apache

[Block all bots/crawlers/spiders for a special directory with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735766/block-all-bots-crawlers-spiders-for-a-special-directory-with-htaccess)

etc.