# Disallow certain bots from accessing certain directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to block certain bots from accessing certain directories on my website. This is almost identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735766/block-all-bots-crawlers-spiders-for-a-special-directory-with-htaccess) except that I don't want to create different .htaccess file in each folder I want to block. I need to use the root .htaccess file.

Regex has been giving me a hard time really. Appreciate your help

Comment: I tried the same code posted on the question I mentioned and some failed regex comboinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a list of folders and add the same condition before each one:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder1/ - [L,F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder2/anotherfolder/ - [L,F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder3/path/to/disallowedfolder/ - [L,F]
```

etc..

Comment: @AhmadAlfy You can use either, the `F` flag returns a 403 forbidden sam as `R=403`, and is the documented way to do it.