# Block Bots from crawling one of my sites on a multistore multidomain prestashop

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt, prestashop-1.5

Hello i have a multistore multidomain prestashop installation with main domain example.com and i want to block all bots from crawling a subdomain site subdomain.example.com made for resellers where they can buy at lower prices because the content is duplicate to the original site, and i am not exacly sure how to do it. Usualy if i want to block the bots for a site i would use

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But how do i use it without hurting the whole store ? and is it possible to block the bots from the htacces too ?

Comment: How do your resellers feel about this? And if the content is identical (no value added) then what's even the point in having them?

Comment: the shop is identical as the main one however the prices are lowered accordingly as it should be for resselers

Comment: You just repeated the original post instead of answering my question....

Comment: From what i know the point is some accounting stuff but that's what my employer wanted me to do so that's what i did, anyway my original question still stands

Comment: Isn't it better to create extra groups for resellers which makes it possible to show them lower prices?

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding your first question:**
If you don't want search engines to gain access to the subdomain (sub.example.com/robots.txt), using a robots.txt file ON the subdomain is the way to go. Don't put it on your regular domain (example.com/robots.txt) - see [Robots.txt reference guide](https://www.becontentking.com/academy/robotstxt/#robots-txt-file-for-each-subdomain).

Additionally, I would verify both domains in [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home). There you can monitor and control the indexation of the subdomain and main domain.

**Regarding your second question:**
I've found a SO thread here which explains what you want to know: [Block all bots/crawlers/spiders for a special directory with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735766/block-all-bots-crawlers-spiders-for-a-special-directory-with-htaccess).

Answer (score 0):

We use a canonical URL to tell the search engines where to find the original content.

https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/

> A canonical URL allows you to tell search engines that certain similar
>   URLs are actually one and the same. Sometimes you have products or
>   content that is accessible under multiple URLs, or even on multiple
>   websites. Using a canonical URL (an HTML link tag with attribute
>   rel=canonical) these can exist without harming your rankings.