# Block crawlers from subdomain via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Our company has temp development urls that are being indexed by search engines. We need to get this to stop via a global htaccess file. By global, i mean i want to drop this access into our root that will apply the rules for each site. Every time we build a new site, i don't want to drop a htaccess file in that folder.

I am terrible at writing htaccess rules, otherwise i would have done it myself. I would appreciate any input from the community.

Here is an example temp url: 1245.temp.oursite.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AltaVista [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} msnbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Slurp
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/oursite\.com" [R=301,L]
```

I've tried playing with this, but like i stated above, i'm terrible at writing htaccess rules.

*Edit*
The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735766/block-all-bots-crawlers-spiders-for-a-special-directory-with-htaccess), however mine involves sub-domains.

Comment: You don't need to escape the destination part of the rule. Just use `http://oursite.com/`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block all bots/crawlers/spiders for a special directory with htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735766/block-all-bots-crawlers-spiders-for-a-special-directory-with-htaccess)

Comment: Mike, wouldn't that prevent the bots from hitting our site?

Comment: @Geoffrey see my edit to my answer and see if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want a universal file to block robots then you can use something like this. This is not specific to a domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(AltaVista|Googlebot|msnbot|Slurp).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Edit: If you're subdomains are accessible from the main root .htaccess file then you can use a method like this and any temp domain it should block access.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(AltaVista|Googlebot|msnbot|Slurp).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9]+)\.temp\.oursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Comment: @ceejayoz Of course there are but I'm not a mind reader. I used what the OP put because he didn't specifically say he wanted to block them all. He could want just certain `bad ones` that he wants blocked. I answered his question in the context of what he was already doing.

Comment: No, that's not how SO works. We don't pretend better solutions don't exist just because the OP doesn't know to ask about them.

Comment: @ceejayoz so why was it down voted when it's what the OP wanted. That makes no sense.

Comment: @Geoffrey no problem glad I could help you find your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want search engines to index the sites, add a `robots.txt` file to those subdomains. It should contain:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

All major search engines respect the Web Robots standard.

Comment: We have over 3,000 temp urls. I do not want to drop/edit robots.txt for each of them.

Comment: @Geoffrey You have over 3,000 sites on a server with no configuration management system? Brave. Should be relatively easy to serve a single shared robots file for all your temp URLs via the server config, though.

Comment: I didn't pick the server config, or how it's done. I just started here a few months ago, and i agree that their setup is garbage. But i gotta work with what already exists. Your response is correct, however in this case it wouldn't make much sense for the server config we have. I also have already tried to get the host to adjust the httpd.conf to point to a robots.txt file, but they won't.