# Secure upload files in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, web-crawler, file-security

I have a Laravel 5 project in which I am uploading files in database in Medium Blob format.

But uploading files in database takes some extra time to execute.

Uploading files in database is a secured way to keep files safe from crawlers or some bots.

I have tried to Upload files to the Public folder. But the crawlers can open these files.

**Is there any possible way to upload files in the file system?**

So that the Crawlers cannot open these files.

I want these files to be Secured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can upload them outside of the public scope. For example, `storage/` folder is a good place. Also, you can grab them using the [file system manager](http://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem). Take a look:

```
$image = \Storage::get('file.jpg');
```

### Edit

A correct laravel installation just allow the content of `public/` to be accesible via web browser. If other directories as `storage/` or `resources/` are public too, then you installation is really incorrect.

Said that, once you upload the files in `storage/` folder nobody can access them except by you using the [\Storage](http://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem) facade. When you call for example `\Storage::get('file.jpg');` it returns an stream of bits that you can allocate them in a temporary folder and then display it in the webside. Once the request has finished, the image will disappear again from public domain.

Comment: Storage folder can be accessed by bots, so this is not full proof. I want the files(e.g images) not to be publicly accessible

Comment: You are wrong.  Only public/ is accesible by browser.  If your storage/ folder  is public then you did an incorrect installation

Comment: @sujitprasad, I have edited the answer. Also, you need to learn more about laravel's infrastructure to know which folders are public an which not.

Comment: I downloaded a laravel project from github. Had made my project on top of that. Also hosted on the VPS server where I have full control.   Uploaded a file in the path "storage/filename.jpg". And searched that path in the browser  "www.website.com/demoproject/code/storage/filename.jpg"  and it opens just like that.

Comment: As I thought, your laravel's installation is not correct. For example, if you are under apache server, generally all public files are located into `public_html/. So, I think that you made the installation there. A correct instalation should be located outside of that directory. You need to set the `document_root` to `public` in your `httpd.conf`

Comment: This is what I have thought for but was trying to search for much easier technique. If I come with some bigger update this will be a task. Anyways yours is an answer.  I hope to find out any simpler technique.

Comment: Now, just put your files outside of `public_html/`, say, `/home/your-user/upload_files/`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the directory this can be achieved by two ways

[LazyOne Answer using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10736599/5594069)

AND

[Using robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

I will suggest to implement both .htaccess and robots.txt as some cheap crawlers ignore robots.txt but they can't ignore .htaccess

Comment: Spam bots can by pass robots.txt as its not binding upon them. Will .htaccess be full proof method?. I want the files(e.g images) not to be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this method

[image-accessibility-for-authenticated-users-only](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/image-accessibility-for-authenticated-users-only)

As this only allows authorized uses to view image