# Automatic robot using site bandwidth

Tags: joomla, ddos

I have joomla 3 on my host . i have also installed RSfirewall and have captcha on all my forms. It seems someone is unsing a distructive robot to use all my resources and my monthly bandwidth limit.
Is there a way or joomla plugin that restirct specify service to each ip in a period of time? for example 20 request in 5 mintues? This is part of my raw access log:

```
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:46:30 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:46:30 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "http://alumsharif.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:46:56 +0330] "GET /index.php/information/bulletin-board/item/376-aghaze-tabtename-doreye-ghayeghrani HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:49:50 +0330] "GET /?format=feed&type=rss HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Feedly/1.0 (+http://www.feedly.com/fetcher.html; like FeedFetcher-Google)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:50:16 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A456 Safari/602.1"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:50:32 +0330] "GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_login HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:50:32 +0330] "GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_login HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:50:32 +0330] "GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_login HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:50:32 +0330] "GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_login HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:50:40 +0330] "GET /information/bulletin-board?switch_modes=2 HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:51:35 +0330] "GET /information/bulletin-board/item/359-happy-new-year-from-dr-fotuhi HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:51:53 +0330] "GET /events/sport-events/item/385-docharkhe-savari-chitgar-12-ordibehesht94 HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:52:47 +0330] "GET /information/news/item/288-dore4 HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:52:51 +0330] "GET /index.php/information/item/504-2015-08-16-07-06-53?tmpl=component&print=1 HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:55:45 +0330] "GET /information/bulletin-board/item/542-tour-3-rooze-kavir-markazi-20-ta-22-aban-94/542-tour-3-rooze-kavir-markazi-20-ta-22-aban-94 HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:55:45 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "http://www.alumsharif.org/information/bulletin-board/item/542-tour-3-rooze-kavir-markazi-20-ta-22-aban-94/542-tour-3-rooze-kavir-markazi-20-ta-22-aban-94" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:56:40 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:56:40 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "http://alumsharif.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:57:00 +0330] "GET /information/news/item/747-shahram-nazero-concert?tmpl=component&print=1 HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:57:07 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:57:08 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:57:08 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "http://alumsharif.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:57:09 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "http://alumsharif.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:57:18 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:57:18 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:57:18 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:58:10 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:58:11 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:58:11 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:59:49 +0330] "GET /information/advertisement/itemlist/category/24-documents-and-resources?format=feed&type=rss HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:13:59:49 +0330] "GET /information/job-opportunities/item/688-takhfifan-co-job-ads?tmpl=component&print=1 HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:01:09 +0330] "GET /administrator/index.php?option=com_rsfirewall&view=logs HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:01:10 +0330] "GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:01:10 +0330] "GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120.png HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:01:10 +0330] "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:01:10 +0330] "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:01:10 +0330] "GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:01:11 +0330] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:01:12 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:01:44 +0330] "GET /component/jcomments/feed/com_k2/363 HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.1; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:02:22 +0330] "GET /information/bulletin-board/item/376-aghaze-tabtename-doreye-ghayeghrani/376-aghaze-tabtename-doreye-ghayeghrani HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:03:44 +0330] "GET /information/job-opportunities/item/694-tejarat-electronic-iranian-co-job-ad HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
185.165.40.80 - - [12/Nov/2016:14:04:13 +0330] "GET /information/graduates-and-media/item/100-farzad-vahid-speech-about-rousseau/100-farzad-vahid-speech-about-rousseau HTTP/1.0" 500 7309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

.

Answer (score 2):

I personally do not think that blocking access to joomla should happen via a joomla module. Via this way the access already happen. So I personally block access directly on the server rather then in the application. Back in time I had a customer who had issues with HTTP spiders who only downloaded some content from his website in order to re-use the content on there own. We ended up using .htaccess files as written [here](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-ip-address/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735766/block-all-bots-crawlers-spiders-for-a-special-directory-with-htaccess). If that isn´t an option for you, you might wish to implement some kind of QoS (e.g. [MOD QoS for Apache](http://mod-qos.sourceforge.net/index.html)). You can also try to optimize your joomla instance (e.g. compress HTML code & pictures) so that there will be less files transfered. For Joomla there are multiple plugins which can do a HTML (inc. CSS) compression. For Images you could run a check against [Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and then compress the images which are announced there. Many images on websites can be compressed without that the user really see an difference (see an example [here](https://compressor.io/)).

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure that this is an answer that you can use, but we were faced with the same problem, so with RSFirewall, we engaged the GeoIP blocking feature, and well, blocked all the countries that we KNEW we weren't doing business with.

Two things happened:

1. The vast majority of the bad traffic was blocked by RSFirewall, and
2. With logging of those blocks turned on, we were able to use the logging database to find the repeat offenders and use THAT information to block them in `.htaccess`.

It was a gradual process, watching logs, and gradually easing back on what was automatically blocked, but there is no silver bullet for these guys unfortuately.

Another possibility, which I've bookmarked, but haven't tried yet, is a PHP class that is being actively developed called [Web App Firewall](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9972-PHP-Block-malicious-requests-using-a-white-list.html).  I can't recommend it, as I haven't tried it, but it might give you some ideas about how you could identify and block certain traffic by implementing it into a Joomla system plugin.

Answer (score 0):

All above advises were true and helped me   i also programmed a custom PHP code that runs whenever index.php  is requested and then I blocked access by hotlink(Direct access) It helped me a lot but still didn't completely solve the problem.

Recently I found the best solution... I started to use a website called CloudFlare.. it works a proxy between my site and user... it completely controls requests and activities and also improves site speed and reduce bandwidth used significantly by caching. it also provides free SSH and tons of feature. after I started using it everything is safe and site is working faster and without any problem...I wanted to advise u guys to use this great service
[www.cloudflare.com](http://cloudflare.com)