# blocking crawlers on specific directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-crawlers

I have a situation similar to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735766/block-all-bots-crawlers-spiders-for-a-special-directory-with-htaccess) that uses the following in the accepted answer:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

It just seems the rules  provided from URL above block access to everything (including homepage level)

- `www.example.com/tbd_templates/`
- `www.example.com/custom_post/`

what I really need is to block access to the directories I specified (`/tbd_templates/` ,`/custom_post/` etc with status code 403) but allow access to the rest of the site structure.

My `.htaccess` is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Make the RewriteRule match only for those paths then, instead of "everything" as it currently does with the pattern `.*`

Comment: can you share the final htaccess code?

Comment: my bad..... nevermind then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
> RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
> ```

As mentioned in the linked answer, this code would need to go in the `.htaccess` file inside the directory you are trying to protect - so that it only applies to everything in that directory (denoted by the `.*` regex).

However, that is impractical if you need to protect several directories. In this case you should change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to target the specific subdirectories you want to protect (touched on in the linked answer, but no example given).

For example, the following would need go *before* the WordPress code block (ie, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker). (You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive, which already occurs *later* in the file.)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(tbd_templates|custom_post)($|/) - [F]
```

The first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive (the *pattern*) is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches against the requested URL-path, less the slash prefix.

The regex `^(tbd_templates|custom_post)($|/)` matches requests for `/tbd_templates` or `/custom_post` (using regex *alternation*) or `/tbd_templates/<anything>` or `/custom_post/<anything>`.

The `F` flag is short for `R=403`. The `L` flag is not required here, it is implied when using `F` (or `R=403`).

Comment: Note that this rule needs to go before the WordPress front-controller, near the top of the file.

Comment: before `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag right?

Comment: @Rfreel It would need to go before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker. Otherwise WordPress could overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you Mr white .. it's working as I wanted to ..one last thing, the `[F]` tag is swappable with any other status code right? let say `[G]`

Comment: @Rfreel Yes, within reason. `G` (same as `R=410`) will serve a 410 Gone. `R=404` will serve a 404, etc.